# glslang is unable to parse built-ins

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vulkan, spir-v

Here is my code:

```
bool ParseShader(glslang::TShader* p_shader) {
    EShMessages messages = (EShMessages)(EShMsgSpvRules | EShMsgVulkanRules);
    TBuiltInResource resources;
    InitializeResources(resources);

    if (!p_shader->parse(&resources, 100, false, messages)) {
        std::cout << p_shader->getInfoLog() << std::endl;
        std::cout << p_shader->getInfoDebugLog() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can get full source codes and project on my [Github repos](https://github.com/bachelorwhc/ShaderRetriever/blob/master/main.cpp).
I build this code with linking glslang related libraries which is from Vulkan 1.0.54.0. And I don't know why I got following error messages:

```
Unable to parse built-ins
ERROR: 0:100: 'int64_t' : overloaded functions must have the same return type
INTERNAL ERROR: Unable to parse built-ins
```

The source of build-ins post on [gist](https://gist.github.com/bachelorwhc/605e754d00da4e503d808c33b2fb27e5).

I tried both two test cases. All can be parsed and compiled into SPIRV by official tools(glslangValidator) successfully. But in case 2, my tool failed in parsing phase.

#### Case 1

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable
layout(location=0) in vec3 inPos;
layout(location=1) in vec3 inNormal;
layout(location=2) in vec2 inUV;

layout(std140, push_constant) uniform MVP {
    mat4 m;
} mvp;

layout (location = 0) out vec2 outUV;

out gl_PerVertex 
{
    vec4 gl_Position;   
};

void main() 
{
    outUV = inUV;
    gl_Position = mvp.m * vec4(inPos.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

#### Case 2

```
#version 450

#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack : enable

layout(set=0, binding=1) uniform sampler2D samplerColor;

layout(location=0) in vec2 inUV;
layout(location=0) out vec4 outFragColor;

void main() 
{
    vec4 texs = texture(samplerColor, inUV, 0.0f);
    outFragColor = texs;
}
```

Dose anyone know what I did wrong?

I have had this problem once, then solved it by reseting project(delete, clone, build again) but did't know why. Now, I got this problem again. however, this time reseting project doesn't help.

Comment: FYI: An "internal error" typically means that the compiler itself broke. So you should investigate why. Also, don't use extensions that are already part of the GLSL version you're using (namely 4.50).

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer is in the Vulkan official project.
I should define following symbol

```
AMD_EXTENSIONS
NV_EXTENSIONS
```

to make those built-ins able to work.